# Trying to run pygame on my conda environment, on my fresh Manjaro install and getting libGL MESA-LOADER error

Tags: arch-linux, python, drivers, manjaro, opengl

I'm running the following code in the python console

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
```

Here is the output from the terminal

```
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /home/souvik/anaconda3/envs/game_env/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /home/souvik/anaconda3/envs/game_env/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /home/souvik/anaconda3/envs/game_env/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  99
  Current serial number in output stream:  100
```

I've just installed Manjaro Linux "5.10.42-1-MANJARO".
I'm guessing there's some driver error for openGL or something. I'd like to know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You omitted to describe how and why libstdc++.so.6 from your home directory is being used rather than the one from your OS (and obviously isn't adequate).

Comment: Could be an anaconda issue maybe?

Comment: Here's an older related SO Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453497/anaconda-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found or also this: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/483 . I'm stopping here, I don't know this tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with `` `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found ``.

- First you should check if you can see `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` in your conda lib:

  ```
  strings ~/miniconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.2
  ```
- If not you should check if it exists in your systems lib:

  ```
  strings /lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.2
  ```
- If this shows the version you can simply copy the file from the `/lib` to the `miniconda3/lib` with:

  ```
  copy /lib/libstdc++.so.6 ~/miniconda3/lib/
  ```

  but also check where the `lib` folder is located in your `miniconda` environment!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Did you by chance mean `cp` and not `copy` in your last bullet?

Comment: Just to help ubuntu users, the library file is located in the directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. Otherwise,it works.